# Regex to get rid of content after the first ">"

Tags: java, regex

Regex to get rid of the content after first ">" in the string below. And putting whatever is there after the first ">" in another string .

eg:

```
String input = <img alt="" src="http://abchdfgjd.com/-430.jpg" width="650" height="430" /> Have you seen <a href="http://www.funnyordie.com/between_two_ferns" target="_blank">Between Two Ferns</a>?
```

Desired output:

```
ans1 = <img alt="" src="http://abchdfgjd.com/-430.jpg" width="650" height="430" />

ans2 = Have you seen <a href="http://www.funnyordie.com/between_two_ferns" target="_blank">Between Two Ferns</a>?
```

can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand your question, this should do it (using [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29))

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String input = "<img alt=\"\" src=\"http://abchdfgjd.com/justin-bieber-ferns-650-430.jpg\" "
            + "width=\"650\" height=\"430\" /> Have you seen <a href=\"http://www.funnyordie.com/between_two_ferns\" "
            + "target=\"_blank\">Between Two Ferns</a>?";
    int pos = input.indexOf(">");
    String ans1 = input;
    String ans2 = "";
    if (pos > -1) {
        ans1 = input.substring(0, pos + 1);
        ans2 = input.substring(pos + 2);
    }
    System.out.println("ans1: " + ans1);
    System.out.println("ans2: " + ans2);        
}
```

Output is

```
ans1: <img alt="" src="http://abchdfgjd.com/justin-bieber-ferns-650-430.jpg" width="650" height="430" />
ans2: Have you seen <a href="http://www.funnyordie.com/between_two_ferns" target="_blank">Between Two Ferns</a>?
```

Comment: String input should not be a part of ans1 . So basically ans1 should contain <img alt="" src="http://abchdfgjd.com/justin-bieber-ferns-650-430.jpg" width="650" height="430" />

Comment: and ans 2 should contain     Have you seen <a href="http://www.funnyordie.com/between_two_ferns" target="_blank">Between Two Ferns</a>?

Comment: @user3561824 I had a copy paste error in the input string. So, it went into the answer. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
String fixed = original.substring(0, original.indexOf(">"));
```

If you want to include the `>`, then just +1 the `indexOf` check.

To get everything after this point:

```
String after = original.substring(original.indexOf(">") + 1, original.length());
```

Comment: and to get the rest of the string after the ">" in another string?

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is not a good idea for parsing HTML. But simple string functions, like split/indexOf will solve current task in a much simpler ways.

Still there is always a *regex* solution available:

```
String input = "<img alt=\"\" src=\"http://abchdfgjd.com/justin-bieber-ferns-650-430.jpg\" width=\"650\" height=\"430\" /> Have you seen <a href=\"http://www.funnyordie.com/between_two_ferns\" target=\"_blank\">Between Two Ferns</a>?";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<[^>]*>)(.*)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

if (m.find()) {
    String ans1 = m.group(1);
    String ans2 = m.group(2);
    System.out.println(ans1);
    System.out.println(ans2);
}
```